# box shadow in css

Tags: css, box-shadow

How can i get these spaces covered with this box shadow?

[image]

**CSS-**

```
.button
{
  height:24px;
  width:120px;
  background:black;
  position:absolute;
  border-radius:2px;
  padding:3px;
  box-shadow:4px 4px 0px 0px #444;
}
```

[Just a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/CwnFt/40/)

Comment: Why not cheat with `border-bottom` and `border-right` rgba color to reproduce the box shadow while not having blank spaces ?

Comment: @Elyx0, Why not without cheat?

Comment: Well try with `box-shadow: 3px 2px 0px 2px #444;`

Comment: @Elyx0, That is ok, what if i need same shadow i used?

Comment: What do you mean by "same shadow" ?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `h-shadow` and `v-shadow` will position the shadow on the box.
If you want the shadow to be closer, change the distance of the shadow.

Test it [here](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/)

Comment: Well, talking about closer shadows isn't a good idea, Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Using close shadows might not get you that much effect. Instead you can use background properties and positions... [Here](http://www.css3files.com/background) is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
.button
{
height:24px;
width:120px;
background:black;
position:absolute;
border-radius:2px;
padding:3px;
box-shadow:2px 2px 0px 2px #444; // changed
}
```